# How the binary multiplication of floats can be represented in C?

Tags: c, multiplication, bit

The binary multiplication algorithm with ints can be represented as follows:

```
unsigned int multiply(unsigned int multiplier, unsigned int multiplicand) {
    unsigned int product = 0;
    while (multiplier != 0) {
        if ((multiplier & 1) != 0) {
            product = product + multiplicand;
        }
        multiplier = multiplier >> 1;
        multiplicand = multiplicand << 1;
    }
    return product;
}
```

This function performs the multiplication of two unsigned ints without the operator "*".
However it does not work with floats because a float is composed of three parts:

[IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPPeM.jpg)

These parts can be isolated as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union {
    float f;
    struct {
        unsigned int mantisa : 23;
        unsigned int exponent : 8;
        unsigned int sign : 1;
    } parts;
} float_cast;

int main() {
    float_cast d1;
    d1.f = 0.15625;
    printf("sign = %x\n",d1.parts.sign);
    printf("exponent = %x\n",d1.parts.exponent);
    printf("mantisa = %x\n",d1.parts.mantisa);
    return 0;
}
```

With the parts separated as ints I can manipulate the bits. But how to make a function that multiplies the parts of a float?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to multiply (a modified form of) the two mantissas and mask the result appropriately, add the two exponents, and fix the resulting sign, then scale appropriately.  Fiddly.

Comment: It's complicated. There are many dark corners you may fall: you need to handle exponents, denormal values, infinities, NaNs. If you are brave enough, take a look at some [soft float implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libgcc/soft-fp). General algorithms are described on the web, here is a [simplified version](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BinMath/multFloat.html). IEEE 757 standard have it all. Also a famous [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: by the way the name of your union should be `float_cast` since it's casting a `float` not a `double`.

Comment: @seleciii44, edited, thanks

Comment: You union is implementaion defined - at best. I'd start with properly splitting the fields without a hack. Note that the C standard does not enforce IEEE754 floating point (although I'd stick with that format here).

Comment: Would be good to describe the motivation for doing this. Likely you can do this but would need to de-normalized floats (and possibly check for non-finite values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution and Answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float multiplyfloat(float multiplier, float multiplicand) {
    typedef union {
        float f;
        unsigned int i;
        struct {
            unsigned int mantissa : 23;
            unsigned int exponent : 8;
            unsigned int sign : 1;
        } parts;
        struct {
            unsigned int mantissa : 23;
            unsigned int b23 : 1;
            unsigned int b31_24 : 8;
        } parts2;
    } float_cast;

    float_cast product, f1, f2, m1, m2;
    product.f = 0.f;
    f1.f = multiplier;
    f2.f = multiplicand;
    m1 = f1;
    m2 = f2;
    m1.parts2.b23 = m2.parts2.b23 = 1;
    m1.parts2.b31_24 = m2.parts2.b31_24 = 0;
    while (m1.parts.mantissa) {
        if (m1.parts2.b23) {
            product.i += m2.i;
        }
        m2.i >>= 1;
        m1.i <<= 1;
    }
    if (product.parts.exponent > 1) {
        product.parts.mantissa >>= product.parts.exponent - 1;
    }
    product.parts.exponent += f1.parts.exponent + f2.parts.exponent - 128;
    product.parts.sign = f1.parts.sign != f2.parts.sign;
    return product.f;
}

int main() {
    float a = 134.337368;
    float b = 151.23000000001;
    float res = multiplyfloat(a, b);
    printf("result  = %f\n", res);
    printf("compare = %f\n", a * b);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Any questions, just comment below. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Multiply the mantissas as integers.
2. Add the exponents
3. Xor the signs.

There are some details.

1. The mantissas should both be normalized, meaning that either the high-order bit is 1 or the mantissa is 0. For full compliance you need to deal with denorms and other special cases -- infinities, NaNs, zeros -- and you may need to normalize, denorm, or overflow (set to infinity).
2. The product is in the range [1, 4), assuming the values were in [1, 2). If the product of the mantissas is greater than 2, some fixups are necessary: increment the exponents by 1; shift both mantissas right one.
3. Exponents are normally stored with an offset. Suppose the the real value of the exponent is e + m, where m is the constant offset. The m needs to be subtracted from the sum of the representations of the two exponents, in order to get the exponent of the product.